# Flexslider z-index positioning on top

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a fixed navigation bar on the top of my screen but when I scroll down the flexslider rolls over the top of it instead of behind, I have tried changing the z-indexs of each container but to no avail, can someone help a css amateur?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#navigation {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
height: 35px;
background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
padding-top: 15px;
z-index = 1000;
}
#navigation a {
font-size: 14px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
color: grey;
} 

#logo {
 float: left;
}

#container {
postion: relative;
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
color: #ffffff;
height: 35px;
text-align: center;
}
#content{
 padding: 50px;
 width:100%
 margin: auto;
}


/* Browser Resets */
.flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus  { outline: none; }

.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.flexslider a img { outline: none; border: none; }

.flexslider {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides > li {
 display: none;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flexslider .slides img {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;

 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.slides:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
 line-height: 0;
 height: 0;
}

html[xmlns] .slides { display: block; }
* html .slides { height: 1%; }



/* Theme Styles */
.flexslider {
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #ffffff;

 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
 z-index = 5;
}

/* Edit it if you want */
.flex-container {
 min-width: 150px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin:auto;
 z-index= 5;
}

.flexslider .slides { zoom: 1; }



/* Direction Nav */
.flex-direction-nav a {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: -17px 0 0 0;
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 top: 50%;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 z-index: 5;

 background-color: #82d344;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#82d344), to(#51af34));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #82d344, #51af34);
}

.flex-direction-nav a:before {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 width: 9px;
 height: 13px;
 top: 11px;
 left: 11px;
 background: url(images/arrows.png) no-repeat;
}

.flex-direction-nav a:after {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 top: 35px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
 right: -5px;

 -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
 left: -5px;

 -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:before { background-position: -9px 0; left: 15px; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:before { background-position: 0 0; }

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next:after {
 right: 0;
 border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
 border-left: 5px solid #31611e;
}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:after {
 left: 0;
 border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
 border-right: 5px solid #31611e;
}



/* Control Nav */
.flexslider .flex-control-nav {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: -40px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 zoom: 1;
}

.flex-control-paging li a {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 margin: 0 3px;
 background-color: #b6b6b6 \9;

 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #b6b6b6;
}

.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
 background-color: #82d344;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#82d344), to(#51af34));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #82d344, #51af34);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #82d344, #51af34);

 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}



/* Captions */
.flexslider .slides p {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 0 5px;
 margin: 0;

 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: white;

 background-color: #222222;
 background: rgba(0,0,0, .9);

 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}


#about {
 
 height: 2000px;
 width: 960px;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}

body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the necessary HTML as well? That will probably make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

in #navigation

you have:

```
z-index = 1000;
```

should be

```
z-index:1000;
```

There are several other places you used that syntax as well. Fix those and i'm guessing you'll be solid.

Comment: Wow. I'm so slow. Been using c++ today so my brain is a bit scrambled! Sorry for wasting your time with a silly error, thank you for the help!

Comment: no worries man.. we all do it. Fresh eyes are a big help.

Comment: @Lewey100: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/